# jquery conflict

Tags: jquery-plugins

my existing js is : jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2   and present my color picker js is :jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2 .  So, I am getting conflict , plz try to help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

have you tried loading 1.4.2 jQuery lib first followed by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();  

</script>
```

and then loading 1.3.2 jQuery lib?

what this does is lets you use $j. for the first lib and then $. for the older lib which should also allow you to keep your old js code.

Comment: Where I have to place this code and how to use this one,plz guide me I am new to jquery